# Node.JS + SQLITE3 I would like to test transaction speed

Tags: node.js, sqlite, transactions, acid

I have Nodejs and SQLITE + sqlite transaction installed because I would like to do some ACID transactions with sqlite

https://github.com/Strix-CZ/sqlite3-transactions

Now I would like to write a nodejs programm to test how many transactions I can do in 1 second. Or, the other way around, how long it takes to commit 1000 transactions for example.

```
The tests should work like this:

first we add database and table and insert into table
User: Harry Balance 10

and then iterate the following:

begin transaction
load balance from user Harry
increase his balance by 1
update his balance
if possible commit transaction

do this 1000 times. And then AFTER the last callback finnished tell me how long it took.
```

But also it would be interesting if it is possible to start a transaction, wait for callback. and when callback finished start transaction again. And do this 100 times. Then say how long it took.

Comment: And what is your specific question?

Comment: The problem is I dont know how to program it. I have knowledge about mongodb but know nothing about sql.